# Reducing the width on a uibarbuttonitem

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have got this bar button which displays the username of a user that has logged in. However I do not need this button to be as wide as it is. Does anyone know a way to reduce the width?

How can I reduce the width of this uibarbutton item?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will help you.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  let rightItemBtn = UIButton()
  // rightItemBtn.backgroundColor = your desired color
  // rightItemBtn.frame = set as you needed
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightItemBtn)

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't but you can add a custom view.